# Android Fragments-Activity Model

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm sort of new to Android and the idea of fragments vs activities.

I'm trying to somewhat emulate the UI from the current Twitter app. I see that the first screen is a `ViewPager` with tabs + `ListView`. When clicking on a list item, you are sometimes presented with a few other screens, following, profile, tweet. These screens do not have the tabs that the original screen had.

Are these new screens individual activities, individual activities w/ fragments in them, separate single activity that controls all the non tabbed screens, or the original activity that held the tabs and the viewpager controlling all the fragments? What is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I won't directly reply regarding the tweeter app, but teach you how to check this for your self.

Every time a new activity is started the whole screen is changed with the activity change animation. That means, whenever it's a new activity, you'll see the ActionBar flying away from the screen and a new one coming in.

If they're individual screens with fragments or not, we can't know without checking the code, but from my experience if they're not using it, they're doing wrong and you certainly do not want to follow their steps.

As per current practices that type of stuff I would most likely code with one activity for the general app (tweets, details, user info, etc), and maybe a couple more activities for login, about, settings, etc. And all the general app be implemented in Fragments that get changed around as needed.

hope this helps.